# Graph Coloring in Prolog

Tags: prolog, graph-coloring

A map should be colored so that no two neighboring regions are given a same color.

Write a Prolog program that tries to assign the given colors to the regions of the given map.

Your program should work with any given map and any given set of colors.

You can have at most two statements (i.e. facts or rules) related to a specific problem instance: one for the given map and one for the given set of colors.

Other than these, your program should be irrelevant to any particular map or any particular set of colors.

The query must be  `?- result(X).`

You cannot use predicates `assert`, `asserta`, `assertz` nor those predicates explicitly defined for I/O, like read, write, print. Among predicates for list processing, you can use `append`, `length`, `member`.

All other predicates you need for list processing must be defined by yourself.

Comment: Since there are some weird restrictions - are you *allowed* to use clpfd? As in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XD7vBbywMc

Comment: clpfd usage is not allowed unfortunately

Comment: Use `dif/2` ...